# problem doing bundle install on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

my situation is as follows:

I installed rvm as a root user on Ubuntu 10.04. As a root user I then installed ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.1 using rvm at location '/rvm/gems/ruby1.9.2-p0/'. Then I logged in as myself on ubuntu and tried creating a rails application in /home/myself/www/myapp. When I do 'bundle install' I get the following error:

'Permission Denied' - home/myself/www/myapp/Gemfile.lock (Errno: EAccess) from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb

I am also not able to do sudo bundle install.

Moreover, when I log back in as root and try to do bundle install from there...I get error:

bash: bundle: command not found.

I am very lost now. How can I get this to work???

Comment: I'll post this as a comment as it isn't a direct answer. This is typically why rvm isn't installed as root. Should you be so inclined, you may try reinstalling rvm under your user account. You may have better luck.

Answer (score 2):

May you should check the permissions of your rails app folder, review the owner and group because I had the same problem and I has solved with:

```
chown -R USER railsapp_folder
```

Good luck!

Comment: I've been doing loads of research on this topic, and this is the ONLY answer that worked for me. So, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you logged in as root, did you activate rvm using

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

EDIT:

How about (logged in as root)

```
rvm use 1.9.2
cd /home/myself/www/myapp
bundle install
```

Comment: I have always installed rvm under the user account, that way I don't have to worry about sudo commands and privilege issues, so I'm out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

rvmsudo runs as sudo in the current environment and from the path it was called from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you've added:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

into your `~/.bashrc` as per the instructions [here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) (see "Post Install").

`type rvm | head -1` should return `rvm is a function` if you've done it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend starting over and installing RVM under your own account.  This [tutorial](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you) is perfect.